# Can someone help me fix my DDA collision algorithm in processing?

Tags: processing, raycasting, dda

I have been trying to make a DDA algorithm for a raycaster for a while now. For some reason I'm having a ton of trouble. The way my code works is that it puts a player into the map that spins at a constant rate. the green circle should be landing wherever the player is looking on the nearest wall. It seems to *almost* work when the line is more vertical than horizontal, but it still is a bit off. the moment it passes the y=x or y=-x line it goes crazy, seeming to shoot off into infinity. I suspect it has something to do with slope, but frankly I'm not really sure.

I have been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbSee-XM7WA) closely, but to no avail. I hope someone can spot the error in my code so I can continue with this project.

Here's a condensed version of my code:

```
int[][] map = {
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};

float fov;
Player p;
void setup() {
    size(800, 600);
    background(0);
    stroke(255);
    
    fov = PI/2;
    p = new Player(12.5, 12.5, -PI/4);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    p.map_();
    p.ddaTest4();
    p.dir += PI/512;
    p.dir %= TWO_PI;
}

class Player {
    float dir;
    PVector pos = new PVector();
    

    Player (float x, float y, float dir) {
        this.dir = dir;
        this.pos.x = x;
        this.pos.y = y;
    }

    // this draws the map array as rectangles
    void map_() {
        noStroke();
        float sf = height/map.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
                
                if (map[j][i] != 0) {
                    stroke(0);
                    fill(255);
                    rect(i*sf, j*sf, height/sf, height/sf);
                } else {
                    stroke(255);
                    fill(0);
                    rect(i*sf, j*sf, height/sf, height/sf);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void ddaTest4() {
        float sf = height/map.length;
        PVector rayDir = PVector.fromAngle(dir);
        PVector stepScale  = new PVector(sqrt(((rayDir.y/rayDir.x) * (rayDir.y/rayDir.x)) + 1), sqrt(((rayDir.x/rayDir.y) * (rayDir.x/rayDir.y)) + 1));

        PVector mapPos = new PVector((int)pos.x, (int)pos.y);
        PVector rayLength = new PVector();

        PVector step = new PVector(1, 1);

        if (rayDir.x < 0) {
            step.x = -1;
            rayLength.x = (pos.x - mapPos.x) * stepScale.x;
        } else {
            rayLength.x = ((mapPos.x + 1) - mapPos.x) * stepScale.x;
        }
        if (rayDir.y < 0) {
            step.y = -1;
            rayLength.x = (pos.y - mapPos.y) * stepScale.y;
        } else {
            rayLength.x = ((mapPos.y + 1) - mapPos.y) * stepScale.y;
        }

        boolean hit = false;
        float distance = 0;
        while(!hit) {
            if (rayLength.x < rayLength.y) {
                mapPos.x += step.x;
                distance = rayLength.x;
                rayLength.x += stepScale.x;
            } else {
                mapPos.y += step.y;
                distance = rayLength.y;
                rayLength.y += stepScale.y;
            }

            if (map[(int)mapPos.y][(int)mapPos.x] != 0) {
                hit = true;
            }
        }

        PVector hitPoint = PVector.add(pos, PVector.mult(rayDir, distance));
        fill(0, 255, 0);
        stroke(0, 255, 0);
        line(pos.x*sf, pos.y*sf, hitPoint.x*sf, hitPoint.y*sf);
        ellipse(hitPoint.x*sf, hitPoint.y*sf, 5, 5);
    }
    
}
```

PS: sorry if I have poorly phrased my question, I'm not really sure how else to put it.